# Can a PHP app run when email is sent?

Tags: php, triggers, smtp

Is there a way to configure a server or a script to execute a php script when an email is received?

In theory this could be extended to other protocols, such as XMPP or SMS, etc.

What I have in mind is a user could send a message to `checking-in@example.org` and this would trigger a script which would then do whatever needed to be done, either irrelevant to the message (an automated message that gets sent whenever some other even occurs, like a server having issues) or related to the message (like it could store the subject in a database that other users could view as an RSS feed).

I know that most list-serve software have a means of sending commands (like unsubscribe), but I'm not sure how complicated the process is and if it is feasible to have something like this on a server-script level.

Would this need to occur at the IMAP/SMTP level, or could it be done closer to the script or HTTP server?

Just to give some context, one of the things I'm considering is a message-based clock in server for one of my work sites. Users could IM/email/text that they are at their scheduled location and this could trigger a script that would update a DB, rather then send the managers a direct message they need to log. This would just be one option (a web-based method is already in the works), but we want to make it as platform/protocol independent as possible. But if we can achieve that, we can look at implementing it for many other day-to-day needs.

Another way of asking might be: is there a way to have "discovery" of users from a server-script app or does something need to be doing a constant check to relevant sources to see such changes?

Comment: Note that IMAP and SMTP are very different beasts. I believe you meant: IMAP/POP3.

Comment: Email, received by whom? Knows users, under your control? See the Pipe Through a Filter answer, the filter can be a CLI PHP script if you want.

Comment: Just curious, 15 years on - I'm here to see if the [discovery] tag can be removed but how did you solve the problem in the end, using a script for a forwarded email or a daemon?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you control your own machine you can configure it to pipe the e-mail through a filter. Simplest would be to setup a new account and setup a .forward or alias

The following examples are for Sendmail, but (all?) Unix e-mail programs offer a similar service.

**Setting up an alias (option 1)**

Look in the directory /etc on your server for your alias file. Add the line:

script: "|/path/toyourscript/pipe.php"

**Using a .forward file (option 2)**

Create a .forward file in your main home directory.

"|/path/toyourscript/pipe.php"

or:

myemail@example.com,"|/path/toyourscript/pipe.php"

If you are on shared hosting then most hosting providers also provide the possiblity to "pipe" e-mails received to a particular account through a script instead of storing them in a mailbox. Check the CPanel setup.

Comment: I don't have control over the machine, but I do have the ability to create a forward file for any messages that come to my user account `melogin@mail.example.org`. So I this will probably be the best way to go or at least what I had in mind. If push comes to shove I can request more accounts that go to the same directory that I can forward once I have demonstrated that the concept works and is worth it. I can always have another prettier email forward to my user account and have that initiate the script. Thanks for the idea!

Answer (score 3):

Use a `cron` job to check for emails through a `pop3` interface. If an "interesting" mail is found, run your `php` script.

Note that the `cron` script can be in PHP too.

Comment: Since my project is one of many within a directory that is itself on a server shared by several other departments, I always look for the most low-key methods. Thus my instinct was to avoid a daemon or cron job that would be a constantly running process. But with two answers pushing this direction, I am now wondering if I am being too conservative or if I simply have to face it that there isn't a realistic way of setting up something that only runs when triggered by an external source (such as an email or SMS).

Answer (score 1):

As jldupont said, it is easy to do ith php itself, simple reading the smtp continuosly with a cronjob.

Otherwise, you could use a [daemon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_(computer_software)), in python for example.

Both ways allow you to do an important thing: check if the sender of the email is a your user (you have the users in a db, right?), or a spambot (nomatter what kind of anti-spam you use, soon or later, checking-in@example.org will be full of spam)

Comment: php itself is also a perfect candidate for writing a daemon.

Comment: +1 for the spam reminder. That is a nightmare I had totally overlooked.